# Can I run both express server and webpack together

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, ejs

I'm a new to webpack and I'm currently creating a node express server application with ejs, and I want to use webpack to bundle my project.

Is there a way I can bundle up all my project files and make them appear in the dist folder

How can I make the express server to run with webpack (cause when I set the express as entry point it doesn't run the server)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to use webpack to bundle your client-side files that are sent to the browser?  Or are you trying to use webpack to bundle your server-side files?  If trying to bundle the server-side files, then why?

Comment: I'm trying to use it to bundle my client side, I'm a bit clueless as I thought that webpack bundles everything including the server files, but it seems that all it does is bundle all the js functionality for a webapp, and minify the code if you want it to. Are my assumptions correct? Please tell me more

Comment: Webpack can be used to bundle server-side code, though there is usually no point.  It has the most use for client-side code where the code organization that is convenient for development is not optimal for deployment and Webpack can turn it into something that is good for deployment and use in a browser.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot it seems more clear now.